# Как получить номер текущей страницы пагинации

Tags: php, wordpress

Как получить номер текущей страницы пагинации? У меня есть следующий урл [http://site/gallery/foto-svyazannie-s-nami/page/2.Как](http://site/gallery/foto-svyazannie-s-nami/page/2.%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA) вообще проверить есть ли пагинация(т.е есть параметр page)и если он есть то получить цифру(номер текущей страницы из моего урла это 2)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

В wordpress переменные запроса легко получить с помощью встроенной функции `get_query_var($name_var)`.
Вам нужен параметр `'paged'`. Это один из параметров `WP_Query` и он содержит номер текущей страницы.
Данный код как раз покажет вам номер страницы.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
echo 'Мы находимся на странице: '.$paged;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Хорошо. Впредь постараюсь более детально отвечать.

Comment: Вы всегда можете внести изменения у уже существующий ответ (или вопрос). Для этого нажмите на ссылку [edit], расположенную под телом ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Такой код даст желаемый результат:

```
$page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];    // получили путь
if (!strpos($page, 'page')) return; // нет слова page в url
$page = substr($page, 0, -1);   // удалили последний /
$pos = strrpos($page, '/'); // нашли позицию крайнего справа /
$num = substr($page, $pos + 1);
```